# How to go from one <a> to another <a> in angularJs

Tags: angularjs

**CONTROLLER**

```
$scope.employee = {};
        $scope.setEmployee = function (employee) {
            $scope.employeeId = employee.id;
            $scope.employee = employee;
            a($scope.employeeId);
        };
        var a = function () {
            $scope.meetingTypes = MeetingService.findByEmployee({
                'employeeId': $scope.employeeId
            }, function () {
                angular.forEach($scope.meetingTypes, function (meetingType) {
                    $scope.meetings = MeetingService.findByMeetingType(meetingType);
                });
            });
        };
```

**TEMPLATE**

```
<tr>
   <td>
       <a ng-repeat="meetingType in meetingTypes">
          - {{meetingType}}
       </a>
       <a ng-repeat="meeting in meetings">
          - {{meeting}}
       </a>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Here I want to open second `<a>` tag on click of first `<a>` tag
The view should like tree view
LIKE :

```
- meeting_type

  - meeting 1
  - meeting 2
```

all services are declared in my `.factory`

Here I am getting meeting Type properly but i want to open list of meetings on click of meetingType `<a>` tag but i am not getting meetings here,
Is `ng-href` is helpfull here ?

Comment: Look into treeview menu's. Onclick of the first <li> would open the <ul> with subcategories beneath it.

Comment: *"Is ng-href is helpfull here"*  .. might be if you want to display details in another view. Otherwise you can use nested `ng-repeat` structure

Comment: how to use nestead ng-repeat here ? or if I used ng-href then how to use it...

Comment: @charlietfl is I need to change anything in my controller ?

Comment: are you using an angular router?

Comment: @charlietfl no not using it.

Comment: Sounds like you should study some tutorials and get better understanding of angular including how routers work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a some sample code which I think demonstrates what you want to acheive -

```
<table ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="TestCtrl">
  <tr>
    <td><a href="" ng-click="setEmployee(1)">Get Meetings</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="meetingType in meetingTypes track by $index">
          <a href="" ng-click="showMeetings = true">- {{meetingType.typeName}}</a>
          <ul ng-show="showMeetings && meetingType.meetings.length>0">
            <li ng-repeat="meeting in meetingType.meetings track by $index">
              <a>- {{meeting}}</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

javascripts -

```
'user strict';
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('TestCtrl', function($scope) {    
    $scope.employee = {};
    $scope.meetingTypes = {};

    $scope.setEmployee = function(employee) {
      $scope.employeeId = 1;
      //$scope.employee = {};
      a($scope.employeeId);
    };
    var a = function() {
      // your service should return this json
      $scope.meetingTypes = [{
        typeName: 'abc',
        meetings: ['meeting1', 'meeting2', 'meeting3']
      }, {
        typeName: 'def',
        meetings: ['meeting4', 'meeting5', 'meeting6']
      }, {
        typeName: 'ghi',
        meetings: ['meeting7', 'meeting8', 'meeting8']
      }];
    };    
  });
```

<kbd>[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f25gje6j/)</kbd>

Comment: Its good,  but how i should set my array objects? because i have dynamic data of meetings and meetingType. henceforth I am getting one problem , when I click on one TYPE that time its child MEETING are comming under all TYPES

Comment: ok its working now, I just set one `$scope` variable in controller eg. `$scope.showMeetings = meetingType;` and then I compared it with clicked meetingType.

Comment: you should make your meetingType and meeting array objects one combined array of json objects like the one I used in my answer. your service should return that.